# Open Nested Treelist menu in Micro Mode on mouseover

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

Here is the example:
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#tree-list

Currently it show the List in Micro mode on Hover and nested list on click event. How can i open the nested menu on mouseover events.

Comment: What Extjs version you are working with?

Comment: ExtJs 6.2 @FabioBarros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this overrride:

```
    Ext.define('Ext.list.Tree',{
        override:'Ext.list.Tree',
        privates:{
            onMouseOver: function (e) {
                var comp = Ext.Component.fromElement(e.getTarget());

                if (comp.isTreeListItem){ comp.expand()}

                this.setOverItem(comp && comp.isTreeListItem && comp);
            }
        }
    });
```